# in Javascript, what is the best practice to convert stringified date to 'YYYY.MM.DD' format?

Tags: javascript, time, format

For example, I get string `'20201101'`

What I do is convert the string to `'2020.11.01'`

Here is what I did.

```js
const dateString = '20201101'

const dateArr = dateString.split('')

dateArr.splice(4, 0, '.')
dateArr.splice(7, 0, '.')

const dateFormat = dateArr.join('')
```

I think it is bit long, so I'm looking for another answer for this.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not long, it's four very readable lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
`${dateString.slice(0, 4)}.${dateString.slice(4, 6)}.${dateString.slice(6, 8)}`
```

Not a very clean way to do it, but it is only one line.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with [replacement patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in a [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#switching_words_in_a_string) call.

```js
const dateStr = '20201101';

const result = dateStr.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1.$2.$3');

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, and readable. But if you're looking for an alternative maybe look at [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```js
const str = '20201101';

// Group four digits, then two digits,
// and then two digits
const re = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;

// `match` returns an array of groups, the first element of
// which will be the initial string, so first remove that,
// and then `join` up the remaining elements using
// a `.` delimiter
const out = str.match(re).slice(1).join('.');

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)